# Mean duration of renewal intervals of 3 states

Tags: markov-chains, renewal-processes

Let $\lbrace X_n,\;n=0,1,2,\ldots\rbrace$ be a three-state Markov chain with $\mathcal{S}=\lbrace 0,1,2 \rbrace$ and the transition probability matrix $\mathbf{P} = \left[\begin{array}{ccc}
0.4 &0.2 &0.4\cr
0.3 &0.7 &0\cr
0.8 &0 &0.2
\end{array}\right]$

State 0 represents an operating state of some system, while states 1 and 2 represent repair states (corresponding to two types of failures). We assume that the process begins in state $X_0 = 0$, and then the successive returns to state 0 from the repair state form a renewal process. Determine the mean duration of one of these renewal intervals.

I have tried following along with the answer in [Mean duration of the renewal intervals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2487203/mean-duration-of-the-renewal-intervals) but I am having trouble applying this to a markov chain with 3 or more states like the one above. I would appreciate any help with this.

Comment: With this particular transition matrix, you could find the expected time to leave state 1 from the middle row and the expected time to leave state 2 from the bottom row, and then the expected time to return to state 0 from the top row.

Comment: @Henry I got expected time to leave state 2 = $\frac{5}{4}$,expected time to leave state 1 = $\frac{10}{3}$ and expected time to return to state 0 = $\frac{11}{6}$. Is this correct? Would E[renewal time] then be the sum of all of them?

Comment: @Henry I have tried $E[renewal time] = \frac{1}{0.6} + \frac{1}{0.7}+\frac{1}{0.8}$ but it was incorrect. Please offer me more insight on how to do this

Comment: It depends on precisely what the question thinks it is asking.  I suspect the answer may be $\frac{0.2}{0.2+0.4} \frac{1}{0.3} + \frac{0.4}{0.2+0.4} \frac{1}{0.8}=\frac{35}{18}$ as the time once you have left state $0$ to return (you are twice as likely to go to state $2$ as state $1$), or $1+\frac{0.2}{0.2+0.4} \frac{1}{0.3} + \frac{0.4}{0.2+0.4} \frac{1}{0.8} =\frac{53}{18}$ as that time plus counting the step from state $0$, or $1+0.2\frac{1}{0.3} + 0.4 \frac{1}{0.8}= \frac{13}{6}$ as the expected time when starting in state $0$ that you are next in state $0$.

Comment: @Henry I think since the question says states 1 and 2 are two different types of failure and the successive returns to state 0 from the repair state (1 and 2) form a renewal process, would it be the return trip from 0 to 1 back to 0 + 0 to 2 back to 0?

Comment: I suspect you need to consider the chances of going to 1 or to 2, so a weighted sum rather than a simple sum.

Comment: @Henry is it possible to go from one failure to another? I think a renewal process always goes from starting to event but not event to event. I'm still new to renewal processes but this is my thought process